# Custom media type in Spring Boot REST causes HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http-post, spring-restcontroller, media-type

Im using Spring Boot 1.5.2 and I have a simple REST controller as follows,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class UserJWTController {

    @Inject
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Inject
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping(value = "/authenticate", produces = Version.V1_JSON_VALUE, consumes = Version.V1_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticate(final @RequestBody LoginVM loginVM, HttpServletResponse response) {
    }
}
```

Constants,

```
public final class Constants {
    // API versioning
    public static final String API_VERSION_MEDIA_TYPE = "application/vnd.test.onboarding";
    public static final String JSON_MIME_TYPE = "json";

    private Constants() {
    }
}
```

Version,

```
public class Version {
    // All versions defined here
    public static final String V1_JSON_VALUE = Constants.API_VERSION_MEDIA_TYPE + ".v1+" + Constants.JSON_MIME_TYPE;
    public static final MediaType V1_JSON = MediaType.valueOf(V1_JSON_VALUE);
    public static final String V2_JSON_VALUE = Constants.API_VERSION_MEDIA_TYPE + ".v2+" + Constants.JSON_MIME_TYPE;
    public static final MediaType V2_JSON = MediaType.valueOf(V2_JSON_VALUE);
}
```

However, this seems to be throwing the following error,

```
WARN 37805 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/vnd.test.onboarding.1.0+json' not supported
```

Curl I'm using,

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate" -H "Accepts: application/vnd.test.onboarding.1.0+json" -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.test.onboarding.1.0+json" -d '{"usernme":"test", "password":"password"}'

{
  "status" : 415,
  "error" : "Unsupported Media Type",
  "exception" : "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "message" : "Unsupported Media Type",
  "path" : "/api/authenticate"
}
```

I'm not sure why the custom media type causes the `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException`. Would've thought Spring Boot should be able to handle this automatically.

**Updated**

Message converter registered,

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(Version.V1_JSON));
    jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(Version.V2_JSON));
    return jsonConverter;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a valid message converter registered? Does it work if you change it to use just application/json? Are you using jackson 2?

Comment: I have added the message converter for your reference. Have I done it wrong ?

Comment: Turns out the media type I was requesting was incorrect. I have added to the answer. Not sure why i didnt realize this earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how I have missed this but it turns out the version and `Accept` header i was requesting was incorrect.

It should be,

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate" -H "Accept: application/vnd.test.onboarding.1v+json" -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.test.onboarding.1v+json" -d '{"usernme":"test", "password":"password"}'
```

I also had to specify the content negotiation as follows,

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.favorPathExtension(true)
            .favorParameter(false)
            .ignoreAcceptHeader(false)
            .useJaf(false)
            .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}
```

and I did not need the `mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`